# Restkit request load handler

Tags: iphone, ios, restkit

As i see in all RestKit documentations, `didWSRequestLoadObjects` delegate function is used to handle service response.

The problem is, if I have a different requests (`postObject`) in my view controller i have to check response type in `didWSRequestLoadObjects` for each request.

Is there a way to register a function before each `postObject` and get each response in different function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of RestKit are you using?
On the last release it is highly encouraged to use blocks instead of a `loadObjects delegate function`. For example, the `RKObjectManager postObject` method has a `success` and `error` parameters which receives a block.

Here is an example of use:

```
RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://some.url"];

//Configure here your manager with response descriptors and stuff..

[manager postObject:someObject path:@"/some/path" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    //Success Response code here
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    //Error Response code here
}];
```