# Restkit loading multiple urls in the same class

Tags: objective-c, restkit

I'm starting with RestKit and I managed to do a query and load it in a TableViewController.

The query returns: idTask, nameTask and assignedUserId.

Until here all right, works perfectly. The problem comes when I want to load the user's name from its assignedUserID (it's other request).

I do the following:

```
- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray *)objects
{
    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
    NSLog(@"%d Tasks received", objects.count);
    self.resultsArray = objects;

    Task *task;
    for (int i=0; i<self.resultsArray.count; i++){
        task=(Task*) [self.resultsArray objectAtIndex:i];
        task.user= [[User alloc]init];
        [task.user getUserDetails:task.idUser];
    }
    [self.resultsTable reloadData];
}
```

For each task that charge user call my class and I load the data on it, but that user does not get to have it available in my class work. His attributes are always NULL.

How can I load more than one object?

Mi class user is something like this:#import "User.h"

```
@implementation User


-(User *) getUserDetails:(NSNumber *)idUsuario{
    [self loadUsersAssigned:idUsuario];
    return self;
}

-(void) loadUsersAssigned:(NSNumber *)idUsuario
{
    NSString *urlGetUser;
    urlGetUser = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MY URL", idUsuario,[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"userAccessToken"]];
    //Load objects from url
    RKObjectMapping *objectMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[User class]];

    //Set relations (keys)
    [objectMapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"idUser"];
    [objectMapping mapKeyPath:@"first_name" toAttribute:@"name"];
    [objectMapping mapKeyPath:@"last_name" toAttribute:@"lastName"];

    RKObjectManager* manager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];

    [manager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:urlGetUser delegate:self block:^(RKObjectLoader* loader){
        loader.objectMapping = objectMapping;
        [loader setCachePolicy:RKRequestCachePolicyNone];
    }];
}

- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray *)objects
{
    NSLog(@"Users recived: %d",objects.count);
    NSArray *result = objects;
    User *u = [result objectAtIndex:0];
    self.idUser=u.idUser;
    self.name=u.name;
    self.lastName=u.lastName;
}


- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    //    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
    //    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);
}

@end
```

**Update:**

How you say, I think that i should use blocks, but I don't know how because I never use it.

My object is returning the correct data, but it arrives too late. I show you my Log and my code.

I have modified the loop how you are explaining. It's something like this:

```
int i=1;
for (Task *task in [self resultsArray]){
    NSLog(@"--- begin iteration %d ---",i);
    task.user= [[User alloc]init];
    task.user =[task.user getUserDetails:[task idUser]];
    NSLog(@"task inside objectLoader of Task id:%@ - name:%@ - lastname:%@",task.user.idUser,task.user.name,task.user.lastName);
    NSLog(@"--- end iteration %d ---",i);
    i++;
}
```

Then the log shows:

```
2013-01-29 10:38:32.075 --- begin iteration 1 ---
2013-01-29 10:38:32.075 task inside objectLoader of Task id:(null) - name:(null) - lastname:(null)
2013-01-29 10:38:32.076 --- end iteration 1 ---
2013-01-29 10:38:32.076 --- begin iteration 2 ---
2013-01-29 10:38:32.077 task inside objectLoader of Task id:(null) - name:(null) - lastname:(null)
2013-01-29 10:38:32.078 --- end iteration 2 ---
2013-01-29 10:38:33.570 Users recived: 1
2013-01-29 10:38:33.570 Object loader of user: 522327,Xavi,Sanchez
2013-01-29 10:38:33.640 Users recived: 1
2013-01-29 10:38:33.640 Object loader of user: 522327,Xavi,Sanchez
```

When the loop it's finished the user object is loaded. Before it the user's object was null. I need use a block or something like this to wait until the user object are being loading.

Comment: Why are you returning User on getUserDetails if you are not using it? You are making an async request, so you will have the same user, not an updated one. I would change that to void.

Comment: And dont mix languages :P you should change idUsuario to userId

Answer (score 0):

**Async Requests**

You are making async request and you are expecting to behave in a synchronous way, you are missing a lot of concepts here. Keeping the explanation simple, this means that you can't expect to get the requested objects at the same time as your code. It will always get after it, as you have noticed. You will receive the objects on **objectLoader didLoadObjects** method, a couple **seconds after** you make the request. Those seconds are the time that your machine is taking asking something to the internet and get a response.

The naive solution is to move the logic that you would like to execute with the objects you get from the request into the **objectLoader didLoadObjects**, on the user. But that is a very bad idea because you are mixing things.

Read about how to use blocks on objective-c and change the way you get the objects, to avoid object-coupling. You really should learn how to use blocks on RestKit. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473823/restkit-request-load-handler/), it could help you.

**Not getting the user info**

Well, first of all, I think you should check if the server is returning something, so you can discard if you are making a bad request because of a bad URL.

Add the following code to check what is going on with the network, it will enable the Network Log.

```
RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network", RKLogLevelTrace);
```

If you are getting a nice response, check how that data is being transformed into an object after the mapping process:

```
RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/ObjectMapping", RKLogLevelTrace);
```

This should poing what is wrong.

If you are not getting anything on the logs, the problem is that your request is not being done. Tell me what are you getting to help you further.

**Loading more than one object**

Each request is expensive. Now you are doing one request to get the tasks, and one for each user on those tasks. If you have N taks, you are making N+1 request. That is not efficient. It gets worst if all tasks have the same user linked.

What you should do is modify the service (if you can), to add the user info that you need on the interface, on your case, add the user name, and get everything on one request. If you need more details for one user you will need a service with the full user info and you make a request just in case that you need and not always.

**Recommendations**

My recommendation is that you use **blocks** to handle the request instead the delegate/protocol way. On my experience, it's always a headache to work with delegates on this case, and the code will be easier to read.

**forin instead of for, it's cleaner**

Instead of the for cycle that you have, try the following:

```
for (Task *task in [self resultArray]) {
    task.user = [[User alloc] init];
    [[task user] getUserDetails:[task idUser]];
}
```

Comment: Do you want me to move the answer from user2015323 to the question? Saw your comment on that deleted answer that it should be a part of question.